# Fold a multi-dimensional array n:m in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Today I have a rather tricky question for my beloved JavaScript stackers.

Given the following situation

- I have an array, containing n arrays (say, n of positive integers, e.g 10)
- M arrays of these arrays do belong to a class (say, m of positive integers smaller than n, e.g 2)
- So in an array of 10 elements, I have 5 classes of *"sub-arrays"*

Now I would want to fold my array to contain all my classes, looking like [[:m]] where all the arrays in the class of m go to.
This could be traditionally solved with an iterative way

```
arrayClasses = [[m]] // initialize m empty arrays
array.forEach((n) => if expr; arrayClasses[m].push(n) // where expr is used to determine the class
```

Interestingly, this could also be done by folding the array (talking of a Erlang way of handling data here), simply by using a transformation function from n -> [m]. However I cannot wrap my head around how this can be done with JavaScript's in-house utilities.

```js
// n = 6 elements contains m = 3 classes
let n = [
  [1],
  [1],
  [2],
  [2],
  [3],
  [3]
]

// can be transformed into m = 3 elements containing 2 elements each
let m = [
  [
    [1],
    [1]
  ],
  [
    [2],
    [2]
  ],
  [
    [3],
    [3]
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you give a concrete example what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I do agree that this is quite an abstract description. I added a JSFiddle as well

Comment: Interesting, however I guess this issue has a much more accurate title